# Awk/sed add a column on condition

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I've a csv file with 9 columns in it. Some of the rows missing col 4 and 5 which means those rows have only 7 columns. I'm facing issue using this file as it is some other application.

Is there a way I can add a empty column 4 and 5 for the rows that has 7 columns.

There are 1960 rows in total in that 120 rows are with 7 columns.

I tried:

```
awk -F , 'NF==7' file1.csv
```

to extract rows with 7 columns but don't know how to check it as condition and add 2 empty columns in the middle for those rows.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] together with what you tried so far

Comment: How many rows is it?

Comment: There are 1960 rows in total in that 120 rows are with 7 columns.

Comment: I tried awk -F , 'NF==7' file1.csv  to extract rows with 7 columns but don't know how to check it as condition and add 2 empty columns in the middle for the rows.

Comment: please [edit] your post to show all this info you are mentioning in comments

Answer (score 1):

First missing test material that OP forgot to post:

```
$ cat > foo
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,6,7,8,9
```

Then, in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } 
       NF==7 { for(i=NF;i>=4;i--) $(i+2)=$i } 
# was: NF==7 { nf=NF; for(i=nf;i>=4;i--) $(i+2)=$i } 
       1' foo
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,6,7,6,7,8,9
```

Notice that the original `$4` and `$5` have their original values. That could be altered by changing `$(i+2)=$i` to `{ $(i+2)=$i; $i="" }`.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a variable in place of `NF`?

Comment: Not sure if it is but didn't have time to test it, probably not now that I look at it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not a good idea to assign _to_ `NF` but there's no problem in assigning to `$NF` as it just expands to whatever the field number is.

Comment: @TomFenech Setting NF to a higher value adds empty fields per POSIX. Making NF smaller has undefined behavior so some awks will remove fields, some will do nothing, and others can do anything else. Adding fields will just cause NF to change automatically. The variable isn't necessary.